# Как вывести данные из двух связанных таблиц в dropDownList Yii2

Tags: mysql, yii2, yii

Необходимо реализовать выборку данных в dropDownList из двух таблиц. А именно название производителя (name) и модель самолёта (model).

-Таблица производитель
--id
--name

-Таблица самолет
--id
--model
--производитель_id

-Таблица рейс
--id
--id_самолет
...

Как я делаю:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'plane_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Plane::find()
    ->joinWith(['manufacturer'])
    ->all(), 'plane_id', 'model')) ?>
```

Если надо что-то уточнить - пишите.

Comment: Непонятно, что должно получиться в итоге.

Comment: @fedornabilkin Должен получиться dropDownList, в котором пользователю отображается не id самолета, а название производителя (производитель.name) и модель самолета (самолет.model).

Answer (score 0):

В классе модели должен быть определен метод реляции, чтобы можно было получить из модели самолета данные о модели производителя. Это в случае, если мы перебираем список самолетов. Тогда код может выглядеть следующим образом.

```
$form->field($model, 'plane_id')->dropDownList(
    ArrayHelper::map(
        Plane::find()->joinWith(['manufacturer'])->all(),
        'plane_id',
        function ($plane){
            return $plane->vendor->name . ' ' . $plane->name;
        }
    )
)
```

Где, `vendor` - это обращение к методу реляции в модели `Plane`. Метод в классе модели самолетов может выглядеть примерно так.

```
public function getVendor()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Vendor::class, ['plane_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Comment: При таком варианте Вы на каждую запись из одной таблицы получите дополнительный запрос в другую. Что только увеличит нагрузку на БД.

Comment: Чтобы не было запроса на каждую запись, достаточно прилепить в запросе реляцию `->with('relationName')`. Это добавит всего лишь один запрос, а не на каждую запись.

Comment: Насколько я помню, чтобы получился всего один запрос придется добавить в него конструкцию `and id IN(...)`. Некоторые СУБД (например `Firebird`) такой запрос обработают гораздо хуже и медленне чем прямой `JOIN`. Также время обработки такого запроса будет сильно зависить от кол-ва записей в таблице и индексов. Но, в любом случае, решать какую именно методику применить только автору вопроса :)

Answer (score 0):

Cоздайте в модели метод получения списка для `dropDownList`, например `getMappedPlaneWithManafacturersList` в котором в `query-builder` опишите получение этого поля. Например:

```php
(new Query()->select(['p.id', new Expression('p.model||m.name as name')])->from(Plane::tableName().' p')->innerJoin(Manufacturer::tableName().' m', 'm.id = p.manufacturer_id')->all()
```

После чего оберните это все в `ArrayHelper::map(...,['id','name'])` и верните наружу.
Соответственно после этого Вы может спокойно вызвать это метод в нужном месте.

Вы одним запросом получите нужные Вам данные. Тогда как получение через `relation` на каждую запись из таблицы `Plane` вызовет дополнительный запрос `select .. from manufacturer where id = ...`, что при больших объемах данных может существенно нагрузить сервер БД. Все это Вы можете и сами увидеть после рендеринга страницы в панели дебага Yii2.